# Recommended Post-SP1 Visual Studio 2008 Hotfixes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, hotfix

Today I had to reinstall. I used to have some hotfixes installed for VS2008 but no longer have them and can't remember why they were necessary. I'm expecting any security-related hotfixes to come through Microsoft Update, but I'm interested in VS bug fixes.

Does anyone have a list of hotfixes that they recommend installing for Visual Studio 2008 SP1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find them all here:

http://kbalertz.com/Technology_639.aspx

Look for the ones with a "FIX" prefix.

Update: This is another good source of information about VS2008 updates.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=Visual%20Studio%202008&ProjectSearchText=Hotfix

Comment: That's somewhat useful but there are a lot there! Which are important?

Comment: Hard to tell - I don't know which areas will affect you.
I'd say definitely apply this latest ATL patch (MS09-035) plus at least the cumulative ones. E.g. 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958017

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB967631

Comment: Page 'kbalertz' not available any more. Can s.o. post a full list here?

Comment: The code.msdn.com pages are not available any more either.

Answer (score 6):

Suggested hotfixes ***(links updated 4/2015)***:

- [KB957912 - Update for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Debugging and Breakpoints](http://support2.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=957912&kbln=en-us)
- [KB958502 - JScript Editor support for “-vsdoc.js” IntelliSense doc. files](http://support2.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=958502&kbln=en-us)
- [KB960075 - VS Dev Environment crash after undocking windows or changing layouts](http://support2.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=960075&kbln=en-us)

If connecting to TFS 2010:

- [KB974558 - Forward Compatibility Update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54d)
- [KB980216 - Error message when running unit tests with Forward Compatibility Update installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980216)

<s>[Complete list of VS 2008 hotfixes (including TFS).](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=Visual%20Studio%202008&ProjectSearchText=Hotfix)</s>

Comment: I just updated the links so they should be working now.

Answer (score 3):

I recently rebuilt my machine. After installing Visual Studio 2008 and SP1 I was wondering about the same thing. In the end I used Windows update to check for updates and it found the following updates:

- KB2465361
- KB971092
- KB72222
- KB973675

Screen shot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFf8H.png

Comment: OK but this will fix security issues only.

Answer (score 2):

All the VS2008 hotfixes are posted in the [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/). You can [search for tags "Visual Studio 2008" and "Hotfixes"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=Visual%20Studio%202008%2cHotfix). You should only install the ones for problems you are actually having. Read through them and decide which ones you need. I would sort them by release date and install from older ones first. Also notice that some are included in other updates, such are the WPF designer hotfix included with the Silverlight tools.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Microsoft Connect - Visual Studio and .NET Framework](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads) as a source of updates for:

- .NET 2.0+
- VS2008
- VS2010

Answer (score 0):

I generally go with the ones that are pushed though Microsoft Update.

Comment: After a clean install of VS 2008 + SP1 there are only security related hotfixes showing (972222 and 973675 related to VS2008).

Answer (score 0):

I thought that you can get bug fixes though Microsoft Update too.

If they don't come down automatically go to the site and look through the "Software, Optional" ones (or in the "Developer Tools" section).

Select <kbd>Custom</kbd> at the first screen and then wait a few minutes while it does it's scan.

However, there aren't any showing for me at the moment so I can't say for sure.

Comment: After a clean install of VS 2008 + SP1 there are only security related hotfixes showing (972222 and 973675 related to VS2008).